# What assets can a creditor make you forfeit in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, bankruptcy

If you owe a lot of money in the UK, what assets can the creditor legally force you to sell to pay off the debts? For example, can they make you sell (or remortgage) your family home?   What law is this covered by?

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, if they force you into bankruptcy, everything, except:

- tools of your trade
- household items (clothing, furniture), however, if these are worth significantly more than a replacement then they can be sold and you get given a replacement.

Short of this they can:

- garnishee bank accounts
- garnishee wages and other income
- seize and sell personal property
- acquire liens over real property

The *cannot* force you to borrow money pay them, however, this may be a better option than any of the above, particularly bankruptcy.

If you are in such a situation you should seek advice on how to best deal with it. Most creditors are willing to negotiate over amounts and timing: something latter on is better than nothing ever.

Comment: Literally "everything"?  Under US bankruptcy law, some personal assets are by law excluded from bankruptcy, like equity in a personal residence up to a certain limit.  Does UK law not have any similar provision?

Comment: @NateEldredge edited to detail exclusions - real property interests are never protected.

Comment: Thank you. However I am still unclear about the family home.  If household items are protected, what about the household itself?

Comment: What is a "real property" and what do you mean by "lien"? Also I am confused by your reference to bankruptcy. You don't need to be declared bankrupt to have bailiffs sent to your house do you?

Comment: @Arnold as a last resort, the administrator in bankruptcy will sell the family home to pay creditors. Real property is an interest in land as opposed to personal property which is everything else. A lien over a property means that it cannot be dealt with (sold, transferred, leased etc.) without the lienholder's permission; they also have a claim on any sale proceeds. No, you do not need to be bankrupt to have property seized.

Comment: Will they sell the family home even if that literally leaves you and your children (say) completely homeless?

Comment: @Arnold: Yes, they will (though it's a long process). You are, of course, free to find an accomodation to rent in that case. If you cannot afford the rent, you may be eligible for [Housing Benefit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housing_Benefit). Look at it the other way: It's not the lender's fault that you bought a house you cannot pay - why should they bear the cost while you keep the house?

Comment: @sleske The OP is not talking about debt secured on the property. So "It's not the lender's fault that you bought a house you cannot pay" doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: @dorothy: Yes, good point. I overlooked that. Still, the basic point remains: If money runs out, _someone_ has to suffer. And finding out who's to blame is tricky.

Comment: @dorothy if you can't pay your debts then *somebody* lent you money; the UK attitude is that paying them back is more important than you keeping a house.

Comment: @DaleM That's very interesting and quite different to the US it seems.  I wonder why loans are ever explicitly secured against property in that case.

Comment: It seems https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/debt-and-money/action-your-creditor-can-take/charging-orders/#what_happens_if_there%27s_an_order_for_sale is relevant.

Comment: @dorothy loans are secured because making someone bankrupt is a long and torturous process. Foreclosing is (relatively) easier; slightly less long and torturous process. In addition you are a secured creditor and rank ahead of the unsecured creditors.